# Can jQuery UI widgets autocomplete work with delegate on clones?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, autocomplete

I'm trying to get autocomplete to work on clones by using delegate, but it doesn't appear to be working in Google Chrome.

Here's my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/uGdm2/

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup try this:

```
var tags = ["PHP", "Perl", "Python"];
$('body').delegate('input.tags', 'focusin', function() {
    if($(this).is(':data(autocomplete)')) return;
    $(this).autocomplete({
        "source": tags
    });
});
var tagsdiv = $('#tags');
$('body').delegate('a.copy', 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('div').clone().appendTo(tagsdiv);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/uGdm2/4/

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work when clone() is true: http://jsfiddle.net/uGdm2/5/ (I need that to work for other events).

Comment: @HM2K Why aren't you delegating the other events?

Comment: That's a mighty good question. I've just turned off withDataAndEvents and so far everything I'm doing is now delegated, so I will do some further testing...

Comment: Here's what I came up with, by using .live() instead: http://jsfiddle.net/uGdm2/6/ Thanks for the pointers. Have an upvote.